# python unicodecsv write string with newline

Tags: python, csv, unicode, neo4j

I need to created a csv file, where one of its fields contains plain text. The text must be saved in utf8, for which reason I'm using unicodecsv. My problem is with the newlines. They are not properly saved. Example:

```
import unicodecsv
text = u'Será que existe racismo desde que existe humanidade? \n\nUm artigo muito interessante do Lance Selfa sobre a origem do racismo, a escravatura, e também sobre como o capitalismo os promoveu.'
f = open('test.csv','w')
w = unicodecsv.writer(f,encoding='utf-8')
w.writerow(['1',text])
f.close()

f = open('test.csv','r')
for line in f:
    print line
```

results in:

```
1,"Será que existe racismo desde que existe humanidade? 


Um artigo muito interessante do Lance Selfa sobre a origem do racismo, a escravatura, e também sobre como o capitalismo os promoveu."
```

when I was expecting a one line only. 
This is just an example. What I really need is to import a csv file to neo4j, but the import step gives an error because of these newlines presented in the text field.

Comment: Probably better to use Python 3, which supports unicode much better, than using a legacy version of Python...

Comment: Anyway, it seems your problem is that newlines *are* properly saved. If you want to just remove newlines, you could always use `text.replace('\n','')` before you write to the file.

Comment: Ok but I want to keep the original version of the text. Ij thia particular example the double newline is not mine , but original

Comment: Well, you are going to have to decide what you want, because the original version of the text includes newlines... You could try using `text.replace('\n','\\n')` ... although again, that is technically not the original text...